# How can i send a welcome message with DiscordPy to the standard notification channel?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

i want to write a welcome message to the standard welcome-channel on the discord-server, but i don't know how to address it.

Normally i would write:

```
await client.get_channel(Channel_ID).send(f"...")'
```

But if I implement a specific channel ID, I cannot use the bot on another server. In the server settings I set a "default notification channel". How can I have the messages automatically posted to this channel, no matter on which server the bot is located?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`guild.system_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.system_channel)

```py
guild = ctx.message.guild
await guild.system_channel.send("Message")
```

Mind that guild.system_channel can be None as some servers may not have a default channel where they receive welcome/boost messages

Comment: Thanks a lot! I try to catch the "None"-Option.